# UWP Persian Calendar Date Picker

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm Just Trying To Use a Persian Date Picker In UWP Application and Trying to Use CalendarIdentifier Attribute But It doesn't have     Persian Calendar Property.

Thanks If you Help me

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e235b20-b21d-4714-b1fb-2fc5f101a347/persian-datetimepicker?forum=csharplanguage. Check the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying to Use CalendarIdentifier Attribute But It doesn't have Persian Calendar Property.

[`CalendarIdentifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.calendaridentifiers) class do have a [`Persian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.CalendarIdentifiers#Windows_Globalization_CalendarIdentifiers_Persian) property. You can just use it for the [`DatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker) in XAML by the following code:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="btnDatePicker" CalendarIdentifier="PersianCalendar" ></DatePicker>
```

Or set it code behind:

```
btnDatePicker.CalendarIdentifier = CalendarIdentifiers.Persian;
```

It  just only has no intelligence prompt inside xaml.